# Template is not valid: Invalid template resource property 'WebServerScaleUpPolicy'

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

    "Parameters": {
        "VpcId": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Description": "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
        },
        "Subnets": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description": "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
        },
        "InstanceType": {
            "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "t2.small",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "t1.micro",
                "t2.nano",
                "t2.micro",
                "t2.small",
                "t2.medium",
                "t2.large",
                "m1.small",
                "m1.medium",
                "cg1.4xlarge"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
        },
         "KeyName": {
            "Description": "The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instances",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
        },
        "SSHLocation": {
            "Description": "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "9",
            "MaxLength": "18",
            "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
        }
    },
    "Mappings": {
        "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
            "t1.micro": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.nano": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.micro": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.small": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.medium": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.large": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "m1.small": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "m1.medium": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "m1.large": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "d2.xlarge": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            }
           },
        "AWSInstanceType2NATArch": {
            "t1.micro": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.nano": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.micro": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.small": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.medium": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.large": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "m1.small": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            }
        },
        "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
            
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "WebServerGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
                    "Ref": "Subnets"
                },
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                    "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
                },
                "MinSize": "1",
                "MaxSize": "8",
                "TargetGroupARNs": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "CreationPolicy": {
                "ResourceSignal": {
                    "Timeout": "PT15M",
                    "Count": "1"
                }
            },
            "UpdatePolicy": {
                "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
                    "MinInstancesInService": "1",
                    "MaxBatchSize": "1",
                    "PauseTime": "PT15M",
                    "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        "LaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName" },
                "ImageId": "ami-00932e4c143f3fdf0",
                "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
                "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }
                },
        "WebServerScaleUpPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "1"
            }
        },
        "WebServerScaleDownPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "-1"
            }
        },
        "CPUAlarmHigh": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmDescription": "Scale-up if CPU > 70% for 5 minutes",
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": "300",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
                "Threshold": "70",
                "AlarmActions": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "WebServerScaleUpPolicy"
                    }
                ],
                "Dimensions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                        "Value": {
                            "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold"
            }
        },
        "CPUAlarmLow": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmDescription": "Scale-down if CPU < 40% for 5 minutes",
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": "300",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
                "Threshold": "40",
                "AlarmActions": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "WebServerScaleDownPolicy"
                    }
                ],
                "Dimensions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                        "Value": {
                            "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold"
            }
        },
        "ApplicationLoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "Subnets": {
                    "Ref": "Subnets"
                }
            }
        },
        "ALBListener": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
            "Properties": {
                "DefaultActions": [
                    {
                        "Type": "forward",
                        "TargetGroupArn": {
                            "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "LoadBalancerArn": {
                    "Ref": "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
                },
                "Port": "80",
                "Protocol": "HTTP"
            }
        },
        "ALBTargetGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30,
                "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 5,
                "HealthyThresholdCount": 3,
                "Port": 80,
                "Protocol": "HTTP",
                "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 5,
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VpcId"
                }
            }
        },
        "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access and HTTP from the load balancer only",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": {
                            "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "ToPort": "80",
                        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
                            "Fn::Select": [
                                0,
                                {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                                        "SecurityGroups"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VpcId"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "URL": {
            "Description": "The URL of the website",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "http://",
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                                "DNSName"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hi This is my template for auto-scaling with load-balancer and also i have attach cpu alerts with scale up/down policy but whenever I am going to create stack I am getting an error i.e  Invalid template resource property 'WebServerScaleUpPolicy'. So please let me know where I am lacking in this.

Please help me out. {AWS CloudFormation Template AutoScalingMultiAZ: Create a multi-az, load balanced and Auto Scaled sample web site running on an nginx Web Serever. The application is configured to span all Availability Zones in the region and is Auto-Scaled based on the CPU utilization of the web servers.

The instances are load balanced with a simple health check against the default web page.

Comment: "Create a multi-az, load balanced and Auto Scaled sample  ..." is this part of some home work or job assignment? As such you were given a broken template and tasked with fixing it?

Comment: As I am creating a cloudformation template and its basically a part of a job.And I am facing such issue in this As I am new in Cloud-formation. I really appreciate if you will help  me into this

Comment: Recommend checking out the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) if you're new to CloudFormation

Comment: Voting to close as it is simply a syntactic error.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have not closed the brace for `LaunchConfig`. I have fixed the syntax below, AWS was throwing this error because `WebServerScaleUp` is not a property of the `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` type.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

    "Parameters": {
        "VpcId": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Description": "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
        },
        "Subnets": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description": "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
        },
        "InstanceType": {
            "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "t2.small",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "t1.micro",
                "t2.nano",
                "t2.micro",
                "t2.small",
                "t2.medium",
                "t2.large",
                "m1.small",
                "m1.medium",
                "cg1.4xlarge"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
        },
        "OperatorEMail": {
            "Description": "EMail address to notify if there are any scaling operations",
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedPattern": "([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid email address."
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "Description": "The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instances",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
        },
        "SSHLocation": {
            "Description": "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "9",
            "MaxLength": "18",
            "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "WebServerGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
                    "Ref": "Subnets"
                },
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                    "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
                },
                "MinSize": "1",
                "MaxSize": "8",
                "TargetGroupARNs": [{
                    "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
                }]
            },
            "CreationPolicy": {
                "ResourceSignal": {
                    "Timeout": "PT15M",
                    "Count": "1"
                }
            },
            "UpdatePolicy": {
                "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
                    "MinInstancesInService": "1",
                    "MaxBatchSize": "1",
                    "PauseTime": "PT15M",
                    "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        "LaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-00932e4c143f3fdf0",
                "SecurityGroups": [{
                    "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"
                }],
                "InstanceType": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceType"
                }
            }
        },
        "WebServerScaleUpPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "1"
            }
        },
        "WebServerScaleDownPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "-1"
            }
        },
        "CPUAlarmHigh": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmDescription": "Scale-up if CPU > 70% for 5 minutes",
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": "300",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
                "Threshold": "70",
                "AlarmActions": [{
                    "Ref": "WebServerScaleUpPolicy"
                }],
                "Dimensions": [{
                    "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold"
            }
        },
        "CPUAlarmLow": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmDescription": "Scale-down if CPU < 40% for 5 minutes",
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": "300",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
                "Threshold": "40",
                "AlarmActions": [{
                    "Ref": "WebServerScaleDownPolicy"
                }],
                "Dimensions": [{
                    "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold"
            }
        },
        "ApplicationLoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "Subnets": {
                    "Ref": "Subnets"
                }
            }
        },
        "ALBListener": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
            "Properties": {
                "DefaultActions": [{
                    "Type": "forward",
                    "TargetGroupArn": {
                        "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "LoadBalancerArn": {
                    "Ref": "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
                },
                "Port": "80",
                "Protocol": "HTTP"
            }
        },
        "ALBTargetGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30,
                "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 5,
                "HealthyThresholdCount": 3,
                "Port": 80,
                "Protocol": "HTTP",
                "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 5,
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VpcId"
                }
            }
        },
        "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access and HTTP from the load balancer only",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": {
                            "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "ToPort": "80",
                        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
                            "Fn::Select": [
                                0,
                                {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                                        "SecurityGroups"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VpcId"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "URL": {
            "Description": "The URL of the website",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "http://",
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                                "DNSName"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No Json is write Please check on https://jsoneditoronline.org/ this URL

Comment: The JSON is valid, but you had it nested in the wrong level :)

Comment: Could you please correct this. Appreciate for your help.
and also let you know that I am using existing AMI

Comment: I have corrected in the JSON that I pasted above, if you replace your template with that it will work

Comment: Hi @Chris Williams
Please find the Error 
Thanks For your help No I am getting "Template is not valid: Template format error: Mappings element count 0 should be greater than 0"

Comment: This will be `AWSRegionArch2AMI` being empty, I've removed it from the template

Comment: @shubhamkamboj You have an empty `AWSRegionArch2AMI` mapping in the template. Remove it if you don't need it (seems to be the case).

Answer (score 2):

there is missing } on end of "LaunchConfig"

```
 "LaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName" },
                "ImageId": "ami-00932e4c143f3fdf0",
                "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
                "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }
                }
            }, <---
        "WebServerScaleUpPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "1"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "VpcId": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description": "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
    },
    "Subnets": {
      "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
      "Description": "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
    },
    "InstanceType": {
      "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "t2.small",
      "AllowedValues": [
        "t1.micro",
        "t2.nano",
        "t2.micro",
        "t2.small",
        "t2.medium",
        "t2.large",
        "m1.small",
        "m1.medium",
        "cg1.4xlarge"
      ],
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },
    "OperatorEMail": {
      "Description": "EMail address to notify if there are any scaling operations",
      "Type": "String",
      "AllowedPattern": "([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid email address."
    },
    "KeyName": {
      "Description": "The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instances",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    },
    "SSHLocation": {
      "Description": "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    }
  },
  "Mappings": {
    "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
      "t1.micro": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.nano": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.micro": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.small": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.medium": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m1.small": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m1.medium": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m1.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "d2.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      }
    },
    "AWSInstanceType2NATArch": {
      "t1.micro": {
        "Arch": "NATHVM64"
      },
      "t2.nano": {
        "Arch": "NATHVM64"
      },
      "t2.micro": {
        "Arch": "NATHVM64"
      },
      "t2.small": {
        "Arch": "NATHVM64"
      },
      "t2.medium": {
        "Arch": "NATHVM64"
      },
      "t2.large": {
        "Arch": "NATHVM64"
      },
      "m1.small": {
        "Arch": "NATHVM64"
      }
    },
    "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {}
  },
  "Resources": {
    "WebServerGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
          "Ref": "Subnets"
        },
        "LaunchConfigurationName": {
          "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
        },
        "MinSize": "1",
        "MaxSize": "8",
        "TargetGroupARNs": [
          {
            "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
          }
        ]
      },
      "CreationPolicy": {
        "ResourceSignal": {
          "Timeout": "PT15M",
          "Count": "1"
        }
      },
      "UpdatePolicy": {
        "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
          "MinInstancesInService": "1",
          "MaxBatchSize": "1",
          "PauseTime": "PT15M",
          "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    "LaunchConfig": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties": {
        "KeyName": {
          "Ref": "KeyName"
        },
        "ImageId": "ami-00932e4c143f3fdf0",
        "SecurityGroups": [
          {
            "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"
          }
        ],
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "InstanceType"
        }
      }
    },
    "WebServerScaleUpPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
        "AutoScalingGroupName": {
          "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
        },
        "Cooldown": "60",
        "ScalingAdjustment": "1"
      }
    },
    "WebServerScaleDownPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
        "AutoScalingGroupName": {
          "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
        },
        "Cooldown": "60",
        "ScalingAdjustment": "-1"
      }
    },
    "CPUAlarmHigh": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties": {
        "AlarmDescription": "Scale-up if CPU > 70% for 5 minutes",
        "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic": "Average",
        "Period": "300",
        "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
        "Threshold": "70",
        "AlarmActions": [
          {
            "Ref": "WebServerScaleUpPolicy"
          }
        ],
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
            }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold"
      }
    },
    "CPUAlarmLow": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties": {
        "AlarmDescription": "Scale-down if CPU < 40% for 5 minutes",
        "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic": "Average",
        "Period": "300",
        "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
        "Threshold": "40",
        "AlarmActions": [
          {
            "Ref": "WebServerScaleDownPolicy"
          }
        ],
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
            }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold"
      }
    },
    "ApplicationLoadBalancer": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties": {
        "Subnets": {
          "Ref": "Subnets"
        }
      }
    },
    "ALBListener": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [
          {
            "Type": "forward",
            "TargetGroupArn": {
              "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
            }
          }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn": {
          "Ref": "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
        },
        "Port": "80",
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
      }
    },
    "ALBTargetGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30,
        "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 5,
        "HealthyThresholdCount": 3,
        "Port": 80,
        "Protocol": "HTTP",
        "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 5,
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VpcId"
        }
      }
    },
    "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access and HTTP from the load balancer only",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "22",
            "ToPort": "22",
            "CidrIp": {
              "Ref": "SSHLocation"
            }
          },
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "80",
            "ToPort": "80",
            "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
              "Fn::Select": [
                0,
                {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                    "SecurityGroups"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VpcId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "URL": {
      "Description": "The URL of the website",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "http://",
            {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                "DNSName"
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is with mapping now

Comment: Hi Govind,
Thanks For your help No I am getting "Template is not valid: Template format error: Mappings element count 0 should be greater than 0"

Comment: Seems like it is working,
May I know what changes you have made for mapping?

Comment: There were issues with indentation and also you did few wrongs in resource section

Comment: `Mappings` is not used all. You can fully remove it.

Comment: Thanks Guys!!!
As I am using existing AMI so When I hit the URL its not showing the NGINX content. So please let m know if there is any issue with this.
Also As I am attaching CPU policies so its not added to the auto-scaling.

Comment: Have you started the Nginx in the server?

Comment: Check if the ami that you are using is already having nginx configured properly.

Comment: Else let me share one template that will do everything for you.

Comment: I am attaching that as another comment.

Comment: Yes nginx has installed on that AMI and also It has deleted automatically as those CPU policies was not able to work.

Comment: Can you check the template that I have shared below and see if it works for you?

Comment: As I have checked that template.
Actually I want to use my AMI on that I have installed some packages 
and want to add CPU alarms as well

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "",
  "Parameters": {
    "OperatorEMail": {
      "Description": "EMail address to notify if there are any scaling operations",
      "Type": "String",
      "AllowedPattern": "([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid email address."
    },
    "VpcId": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description": "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
    },
    "Subnets": {
      "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
      "Description": "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a list of at least two existing subnets associated with at least two different availability zones. They should be residing in the selected Virtual Private Cloud."
    },
    "KeyName": {
      "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    },
    "WebServerCapacity": {
      "Default": "2",
      "Description": "The initial number of WebServer instances",
      "Type": "Number",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10 EC2 instances."
    },
    "InstanceType": {
      "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "t2.small",
      "AllowedValues": [
        "t1.micro",
        "t2.nano",
        "t2.micro",
        "t2.small",
        "t2.medium",
        "t2.large",
        "m1.small",
        "m1.medium",
        "m1.large",
        "m1.xlarge",
        "m2.xlarge",
        "m2.2xlarge",
        "m2.4xlarge",
        "m3.medium",
        "m3.large",
        "m3.xlarge",
        "m3.2xlarge",
        "m4.large",
        "m4.xlarge",
        "m4.2xlarge",
        "m4.4xlarge",
        "m4.10xlarge",
        "c1.medium",
        "c1.xlarge",
        "c3.large",
        "c3.xlarge",
        "c3.2xlarge",
        "c3.4xlarge",
        "c3.8xlarge",
        "c4.large",
        "c4.xlarge",
        "c4.2xlarge",
        "c4.4xlarge",
        "c4.8xlarge",
        "g2.2xlarge",
        "g2.8xlarge",
        "r3.large",
        "r3.xlarge",
        "r3.2xlarge",
        "r3.4xlarge",
        "r3.8xlarge",
        "i2.xlarge",
        "i2.2xlarge",
        "i2.4xlarge",
        "i2.8xlarge",
        "d2.xlarge",
        "d2.2xlarge",
        "d2.4xlarge",
        "d2.8xlarge",
        "hi1.4xlarge",
        "hs1.8xlarge",
        "cr1.8xlarge",
        "cc2.8xlarge",
        "cg1.4xlarge"
      ],
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },
    "SSHLocation": {
      "Description": " The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    }
  },
  "Mappings": {
    "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
      "t1.micro": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.nano": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.micro": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.small": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.medium": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "t2.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m1.small": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m1.medium": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m1.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m1.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m2.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m2.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m2.4xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m3.medium": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m3.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m3.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m3.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m4.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m4.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m4.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m4.4xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "m4.10xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c1.medium": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c1.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c3.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c3.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c3.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c3.4xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c3.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c4.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c4.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c4.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c4.4xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "c4.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "g2.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVMG2"
      },
      "g2.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVMG2"
      },
      "r3.large": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "r3.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "r3.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "r3.4xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "r3.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "i2.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "i2.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "i2.4xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "i2.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "d2.xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "d2.2xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "d2.4xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "d2.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "hi1.4xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "hs1.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "cr1.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      },
      "cc2.8xlarge": {
        "Arch": "HVM64"
      }
    },
    "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
      "us-east-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-0080e4c5bc078760e",
        "HVMG2": "ami-0aeb704d503081ea6"
      },
      "us-west-2": {
        "HVM64": "ami-01e24be29428c15b2",
        "HVMG2": "ami-0fe84a5b4563d8f27"
      },
      "us-west-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-0ec6517f6edbf8044",
        "HVMG2": "ami-0a7fc72dc0e51aa77"
      },
      "eu-west-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-08935252a36e25f85",
        "HVMG2": "ami-0d5299b1c6112c3c7"
      },
      "eu-west-2": {
        "HVM64": "ami-01419b804382064e4",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      },
      "eu-west-3": {
        "HVM64": "ami-0dd7e7ed60da8fb83",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      },
      "eu-central-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-0cfbf4f6db41068ac",
        "HVMG2": "ami-0aa1822e3eb913a11"
      },
      "eu-north-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-86fe70f8",
        "HVMG2": "ami-32d55b4c"
      },
      "ap-northeast-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-00a5245b4816c38e6",
        "HVMG2": "ami-09d0e0e099ecabba2"
      },
      "ap-northeast-2": {
        "HVM64": "ami-00dc207f8ba6dc919",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      },
      "ap-northeast-3": {
        "HVM64": "ami-0b65f69a5c11f3522",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      },
      "ap-southeast-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-05b3bcf7f311194b3",
        "HVMG2": "ami-0e46ce0d6a87dc979"
      },
      "ap-southeast-2": {
        "HVM64": "ami-02fd0b06f06d93dfc",
        "HVMG2": "ami-0c0ab057a101d8ff2"
      },
      "ap-south-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-0ad42f4f66f6c1cc9",
        "HVMG2": "ami-0244c1d42815af84a"
      },
      "us-east-2": {
        "HVM64": "ami-0cd3dfa4e37921605",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      },
      "ca-central-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-07423fb63ea0a0930",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      },
      "sa-east-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-05145e0b28ad8e0b2",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      },
      "cn-north-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-053617c9d818c1189",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      },
      "cn-northwest-1": {
        "HVM64": "ami-0f7937761741dc640",
        "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
      }
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "NotificationTopic": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
      "Properties": {
        "Subscription": [
          {
            "Endpoint": {
              "Ref": "OperatorEMail"
            },
            "Protocol": "email"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "WebServerScaleUpPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
        "AutoScalingGroupName": {
          "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
        },
        "Cooldown": "60",
        "ScalingAdjustment": "1"
      }
    },
    "WebServerScaleDownPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
        "AutoScalingGroupName": {
          "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
        },
        "Cooldown": "60",
        "ScalingAdjustment": "-1"
      }
    },
    "CPUAlarmHigh": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties": {
        "AlarmDescription": "Scale-up if CPU > 60% for 10 minutes",
        "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic": "Average",
        "Period": "300",
        "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
        "Threshold": "60",
        "AlarmActions": [
          {
            "Ref": "WebServerScaleUpPolicy"
          }
        ],
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
            }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold"
      }
    },
    "CPUAlarmLow": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties": {
        "AlarmDescription": "Scale-down if CPU < 40% for 10 minutes",
        "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic": "Average",
        "Period": "300",
        "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
        "Threshold": "40",
        "AlarmActions": [
          {
            "Ref": "WebServerScaleDownPolicy"
          }
        ],
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
            }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold"
      }
    },
    "ApplicationLoadBalancer": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties": {
        "Subnets": {
          "Ref": "Subnets"
        }
      }
    },
    "ALBListener": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [
          {
            "Type": "forward",
            "TargetGroupArn": {
              "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
            }
          }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn": {
          "Ref": "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
        },
        "Port": "80",
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
      }
    },
    "ALBTargetGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 10,
        "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 5,
        "HealthyThresholdCount": 2,
        "Port": 80,
        "Protocol": "HTTP",
        "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 5,
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VpcId"
        },
        "TargetGroupAttributes": [
          {
            "Key": "stickiness.enabled",
            "Value": "true"
          },
          {
            "Key": "stickiness.type",
            "Value": "lb_cookie"
          },
          {
            "Key": "stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds",
            "Value": "30"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "WebServerGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
          "Ref": "Subnets"
        },
        "LaunchConfigurationName": {
          "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
        },
        "MinSize": "1",
        "MaxSize": "10",
        "DesiredCapacity": {
          "Ref": "WebServerCapacity"
        },
        "TargetGroupARNs": [
          {
            "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
          }
        ],
        "NotificationConfiguration": {
          "TopicARN": {
            "Ref": "NotificationTopic"
          },
          "NotificationTypes": [
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR"
          ]
        }
      },
      "CreationPolicy": {
        "ResourceSignal": {
          "Timeout": "PT5M",
          "Count": {
            "Ref": "WebServerCapacity"
          }
        }
      },
      "UpdatePolicy": {
        "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
          "MinInstancesInService": "1",
          "MaxBatchSize": "1",
          "PauseTime": "PT5M",
          "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    "LaunchConfig": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Metadata": {
        "Comment": "Configure the bootstrap helpers to install the Nginx Web Server",
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
          "config": {
            "packages": {
              "yum": {
                "java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel": []
              }
            },
            "files": {
              "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "[main]\n",
                      "stack=",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                      },
                      "\n",
                      "region=",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      "\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "mode": "000400",
                "owner": "root",
                "group": "root"
              },
              "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                      "triggers=post.update\n",
                      "path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                      "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                      "         --stack ",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                      },
                      "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                      "         --region ",
                      {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      "\n",
                      "runas=root\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "mode": "000400",
                "owner": "root",
                "group": "root"
              }
            },
            "services": {
              "sysvinit": {
                "cfn-hup": {
                  "enabled": "true",
                  "ensureRunning": "true",
                  "files": [
                    "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf",
                    "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": {
          "Fn::FindInMap": [
            "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            {
              "Fn::FindInMap": [
                "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                {
                  "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "Arch"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "InstanceType"
        },
        "SecurityGroups": [
          {
            "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
          }
        ],
        "KeyName": {
          "Ref": "KeyName"
        },
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                "yum install nginx -y; service nginx start; chkconfig nginx on;",
                "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap;",
                "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                "         --stack ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                },
                "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                "         --region ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                "\n",
                "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                "         --stack ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                },
                "         --resource WebServerGroup ",
                "         --region ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                "\n"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enable HTTP access via port 80 locked down to the ELB and SSH access",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "80",
            "ToPort": "80",
            "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
              "Fn::Select": [
                0,
                {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                    "SecurityGroups"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "22",
            "ToPort": "22",
            "CidrIp": {
              "Ref": "SSHLocation"
            }
          }
        ],
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VpcId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "WebsiteURL": {
      "Description": "URL for newly Nginx stack",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "http://",
            {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                "DNSName"
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I have checked this template.
Actually I want to use my AMI on that I have installed some packages 
and want to add CPU alarms as well

Comment: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup DELETE_IN_PROGRESS
I got this in alarms

Comment: Govind Can I get your email Id So that I can Chat with you for the same?

Comment: you can visit www.elngovind.com go get it.